# Read multiple sockets from single thread [low-latency]

Tags: c, unix, tcpclient, low-latency, single-threaded

As a network client I would like to follow the input from two TCP connections. Both servers send a few packets per second. Each packet is small in size when compared to the available bandwidth.

Ideally we'd like to read both sockets from a single thread for the best latency. My initial plan was to use `FIONREAD` from ioctl(2) on each connection in a loop, and only read when data is available. Are there other options? CPU consumption is less relevant than low latency.

Comment: Use `select()` and non-blocking mode.

Comment: Or use `poll` (if you are on a Posix system).

Comment: @user207421, If you use `select`, you don't need non-blocking handles.

Comment: @ikegami You do actually. This is a common misconception. It *appears* as though you don't, but in practice numerous subtle errors are possible if you use `select()` with blocking-mode sockets.

Comment: @user207421, Name one?

Comment: @ikegami `accept()` can return null. `read()` and `write()` can return -1/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK. How many do you need?

Comment: @ikegami See also the [*man select* page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), near the bottom.

Comment: @user207421 Re "*accept() can return null.*", So? /// Re "*read() and write() can return -1/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.*", well yeah, which is why you use select to let you know when it wouldn't return that.

Comment: @user207421, Re "*See also the man select page, near the bottom.*", The example that doesn't use non-blocking socket?

Comment: "*follow the input from two TCP connections*" What do you mean by follow? Follow it where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use one of these I/O multiplexing primitives:

- Non-blocking sockets which would give you similar behavior as your `ioctl(2)`.  Usually, it's combined with one of the options below to avoid a busy loop.
- `select()`; "On Linux [...] it may be safer to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block"
- `poll()`
- `epoll()` (Linux)
- POSIX aio_ family of functions. Not sure it's used much and Linux the library spawns threads.
- uring (Linux)